# Restangular crossdomain request. What I do wrong?

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, cors, restangular, cross-domain-policy

I have domain `sub.example.com` with configured restangular:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
});
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({
    'withCredentials': true
});
```

Then I'm building other factory via:

```
return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://api.example.com');
});
```

And, obviously, getting error **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sub.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.**. How should I configure server/client to get working crossdomain requests?

// upd

I'm using Yii on backend and sending next header
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', true);`

Comment: Your server-side header doesn't seem to be correct: the key and value pair are both in the key side - so the mapping doesn't mean anything.
(Access-Control-Allow-Origin, "*")
see  http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found solution.

At first, when using credentials - we can't use * for Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Then, XHR sends OPTIONS request that should be handled well and send CORS headers.

```
// scheme required, here can be multiple origins concatenated by space if using credentials
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sub.example.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, X-Requested-With');
// without credentials we can use * for origin
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true);
```

Then we can simply use crossdomain ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I am encountering the exact same issue.

Comment: @ChuckConway np. Glad to see that my answer helped somebody.

Comment: Very lost with how do I set this?

Comment: I'm guessing this is some API side PHP.

Comment: @AJ_83 anywhere in your backend before any headers are sent.